Remove extra line from Kusto linechart
As a result of this SO post I had a kql script that creates a linechart. I added more rows to the data datatable and now a line connects the largest Stage_Num values. I'm still learning everything kusto and trying to research the 'Series' keyword (there is not much out there), but I didn't expect that line to appear. How can I alter my query to get rid of that line?

In fact, simply converting the chart to a stackedareachart gives me almost what I want (no top line), but I don't need the stack filler color:

Query
let data = datatable(Place:string, Date:string, Stage_Num:int, String:string)
[
    "Room1", "1/30/23", 3, "Winner",
    "Room4", "2/4/23", 3, "Winner",
];
let mytable = datatable(Place:string, Date:string, Stage_Num:int)
[
  "Room1", "1/30/23", 3,
  "Room2", "2/1/23",  1,           <-- new row
  "Room3", "2/3/23",  2,           <-- new row
  "Room4", "2/4/23",  3,
]
;
mytable
| project Place, Date, Stage_Num, String = "Hello Rithwik"
| union (data)
| project Place, Date, Stage_Num, String
| order by Date asc
| render linechart with ( 
    legend = hidden,
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    xcolumn=Place, xaxis=linear, ycolumns=Stage_Num, ytitle="Stage", xtitle="Place", series=String
)
;



How can I alter my query to get rid of that line?

In first table the String column stores Winner as its value, whereas the second table doesn't have String column. While trying to union these two tables, in project you are adding String column with a different value Data which mismatches the String column and value Winner from first table. So, it's creating a new line. Try with the below code, it stores same column and value as first table stores i.e., Data which rids that line as shown in the output below.
let data = datatable(Place:string, Date:string, Stage_Num:int, String:string)
[
    "Room1", "1/30/23", 3, "Data",
    "Room4", "2/4/23", 3, "Data",
];
let mytable = datatable(Place:string, Date:string, Stage_Num:int)
[
  "Room1", "1/30/23", 3,
  "Room2", "2/1/23", 1,           
  "Room3", "2/3/23", 2,           
  "Room4", "2/4/23", 3,
];
mytable
| project Place, Date, Stage_Num, String = "Data"
| union (data)
| project Place, Date, Stage_Num, String
| order by Date asc
| render linechart with ( 
    legend = hidden,
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    xcolumn=Place, xaxis=linear, ycolumns=Stage_Num, ytitle="Stage", xtitle="Place", series=String
);

Output:


But now my colored data points are gone
